# How to send/email an attchment file with sendmail command using python3.7 without saving password

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sendmail, ubuntu-18.04

I have written some code in python3.7 "script.py" on ubuntu ec2 server "my-server" to generate the excel file "data.xlxs" and also installed and configured the sendmail with smtp user and password on same server.

To configure the sendmail I followed the below link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-sendmail.html

Normally, below command is working properly on *`ubuntu ec2`* server *`"my-server"`* to send eamil.

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -vf sender@example.com recipient@example.com
```

I copied below code from somewhere, emails are going with this code, but I don't know exactly how to add the attach file in same code.

```
!/usr/bin/python3

SENDMAIL = "/usr/sbin/sendmail" # sendmail path

FROM = "abc@example.com"

TO = ["xyz@example.com","qwerty@example.com"]

SUBJECT = "Data List"

TEXT = "Hi All, Please find the attachment."

message = """\

From: %s

To: %s

Subject: %s

%s

""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

import os

p = os.popen("%s -t -i" % SENDMAIL, "w")

p.write(message)

status = p.close()

if status:

    print "Sendmail exit status", status
```

I saw lots of examples on google. So peoples are using the sender's password to send email.

I want to email the generated file *`"data.xlxs"`* file trough the same script *`"script.py"`* without using sender's password in script.

Please help me.

Comment: have you considered using Python's builtin `smtplib` and `email.message.EmailMessage` here? That'll keep everything more convenient in Python, remove the need to format an email message directly and easily add an attachment...

Comment: Why don't you use [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) instead?

Comment: Hi Jon Clements, Thanks for your reply. I want only a single command which can be use in my python script to send email with excel attachment. I don't want a separate script.

Comment: Below command is sending the email but file is not attaching properly.
"mailx -a data.xlsx -s "Instances list" -r abc@example.com xyz@example.com"

After executing this command, output is like this
Instance_List.xlsx
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
  
 How to resolve this, please help anyone, thanks in advance.